# GoogleSheet formula for calculating time duration between two groups of time stamps

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Looking for a formula that will calculate groups of time-based on a day if there is more than an hour between the two groups. If it is less than one hour leave as is.
For example, there are a total of 3hrs and 10 min of time stamps on Thursday 33min (Blue) + 2hrs 36min (Gray) = 3:hrs and 10min total duration.
In the table above I would like the Start Time, End Time (which already have the MIN and MAX calculation, and the total amount of timestamps for each group. I will have 60,000 records that I need this formula for.

Comment: Here is the GoogleSheet I am working off of. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TH9pFxHRrB8GvGiezzQjjzjUocS0oZrkvbc2Xz-MDYc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but gets you where you want.

> I wonder if someone could do the whole task in one formula ..keen to
> learn how)

**DIY approach**: create 2 tables as helpers:

Spreadsheet demo: [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TH9pFxHRrB8GvGiezzQjjzjUocS0oZrkvbc2Xz-MDYc/edit#gid=703759492)

**Table 1 (for mornings timings):**

```
=query(arrayformula({A2:A,C2:C,timevalue(C2:C)}),"Select dayofweek(Col1),count(Col1),min(Col2),max(Col2),max(Col3)-min(Col3) 
where Col1 is not null and Col2 < timeofday '12:00:00' group by dayofweek(Col1) 
label dayofweek(Col1) 'Evenings',count(Col1) 'Record',min(Col2) 'Start Time',max(Col2) 'End Time',max(Col3)-min(Col3) 'Total Duration'")
```

**Output Table 1:**

[image]

**Table 2 (for evenings timings):**

```
=query(arrayformula({A2:A,C2:C,timevalue(C2:C)}),"Select dayofweek(Col1),count(Col1),min(Col2),max(Col2),max(Col3)-min(Col3) 
where Col1 is not null and Col2 > timeofday '12:00:00' group by dayofweek(Col1) 
label dayofweek(Col1) 'Evenings',count(Col1) 'Record',min(Col2) 'Start Time',max(Col2) 'End Time',max(Col3)-min(Col3) 'Total Duration'")
```

**Output Table 2:**

[image]

Then on your initial table you combine the results of both tables using vlookup:

[image]

**Records:**

```
=arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(F4:F8,F14:G20,2,0)+VLOOKUP(F4:F8,F25:G31,2,0)))
```

**Start Time:**

```
=arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(F4:F8,F14:H20,3,0)))
```

**End Time:**

```
=arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(F4:F8,F25:I31,4,0)))
```

**Total Duration:**

```
=arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(F4:F8,F14:J20,5,0)+VLOOKUP(F4:F8,F25:J31,5,0)))
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful and works for what I need. I actually added more dates to your spreadsheet. Is there a way in the Query to list the days of the week in order from Sunday - Saturday? If not, it is more of a wish than a need. But it would be helpful.

Comment: If you're asking about the final table (orange), that's straightforward: you just need to order them manually and the VLOOKUPs will do the job. Answer has been updated. If this has solved your problem, you can also upvote the response. Thanks

Comment: In the Spreadsheet demo you created. Is there a way to order the weekday from Sunday to Saturday in Query 1? I would like to put all the tables side by side for a better analysis. Currently, Query Table 1 is out of order.
 
Query Table 1
Friday
Monday
Saturday
Sunday
Thursday
Tuesday
Wednesday


Would love it to be in order: 
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday

Comment: Using dayofweek(Col1) will be the solution then. We will change from considering Col1 the range B2:B and use A2:A instead, so that dayofweek can be used without error. I've updated my answer and the spreadsheet

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much for your assistance.